# Laravel filter data after with closure

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, eloquent

I have one quite simple question, Imagine I have `Orders` model and now I am writing something like that :

```
Order::where('status', 1)->with('orderer')->get();
```

Ok. It's simple and returns something like that:

```
 {
      id: 1,
      price: 200,
      status: 1,
      income: 21,
      orderer_id: 4,
      orderer: {
        //some orderer fields
      }
  }
```

now I don't want to get the whole object, I want to remove `income`, `orderer_id` and `status` properties from data. if I write something like that : `get(["id", "price"])` I end up without orderer object (`get(["id", "price", "orderer"])` doesn't work too), I couldn't make it work even using select(), so what is the solution?  Also I don't want to hide it from everyone, for example admin should know income but user shouldn't, so  $hidden field will not work.

Comment: When limiting the selected columns, you have to include `orderer_id`. Otherwise, the `orderer` relationship can't work.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you actually give people some credit for their work. In all your questions you never give anyone some credit.

Comment: I'm sorry for that.I will.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `select()` but make sure select does not take array but comma separated arguments :

```
$orders = Order::where('status', 1)->with('orderer');

if($user->role == 'admin'){
   $orders->select('id','income','status','price');
}
else{
   $orders->select('id','status','price');
}

$orders = $orders->get();
```

Above will first check the current logged in user's role and accordingly will select the columns required.

Answer (score 0):

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/hiding-fields-when-querying-laravel-eloquent-models

In your Order Eloquent model:

```
protected $hidden = array('hide_this_field', 'and_that_field');
```

Edit: You want to filter based on role like Admin or User, next time please write that down in your question as well. Well a solution for that is to capture the DB query result, and walk that array, then unset properties of the model if the user is not an admin.

Edit2: I also see a discussion here which might help. Some user suggested using middle ware:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hide-eloquent-fields-based-on-user-role-or-any-model

Comment: No, no I don't want to hide it from everyone, for example admin should know income but user shouldn't

Comment: Then you should add that to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a built in Laravel way to handle this, you could use API Resources: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources

`php atrisan make:resource OrderResource`

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $current_role = $request->user()->role; //or however you determine admin etc

        $out = [
            'id'    => $this->id,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'orderer'=> $this->orderer,
        ];

        if($current_role == 'admin'){

            $out['income'] = $this->income;
            $out['status'] = $this->status;

        }
        return $out;
    }
}
```

In your Controller action

`return OrderResource::collection(Order::where('status', 1)->with('orderer')->get());`

If you want something a little more robust, consider https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractal